# Causality analysis

Tags: machine-learning, correlation

I'm trying to find causes for my lack of sleep through data. I'm hoping to be able to input information throughout the day like "drank coffee", "Exercised", "meditation","what I ate for dinner" ... and log the amount/quality of sleep.

I would finish with something like this data wise:

```
Day |  Coffee   | Baby cried :( | Sleep
1   |  yes(9am) | yes(2am-1hr)  | 4hrs
2   |  yes(8am) | no            | 6hrs
3   |  yes(4pm) | no            | 3hrs
4   |  no(9am)  | yes(3am-2hr)  | 8hrs
```

*(This data example is small and missing columns and is a simple example)* 
The idea is to see what influences my sleep most, it might be to stop caffeine after 12pm...OR working out for 2days in a row means I get better sleep.

Can anybody point me in the right direction for this, what method could make guesses on what leads to longer sleep or shorter sleeps? Bearing in mind that it's not going to be a huge amount of data (if a person logs a year for example, it would be 365 data points).

Comment: Causal inference from time series is harder than causal inference in independent data samples. You have to assume that the underlying data generating process isn't changing over time, and you have to disentangle the persistent effects of inputs from the effects of things that newly happen. Then you have all if the classical problems with causal inference stemming from omitted variables. TLDR: best that you're likely to get I'd an association. All that said: you might look into vector autoregressions. Basically you jointly forecast the outcome and all the things that go into it.

Comment: @generic_user is right:  causal inference with dependent multivariate time series data is a bit more challenging than your run of the mill descriptive or correlation analyses.  But I'm not even sure you need to perform a causal analysis.  Since you are only interested in learning about YOUR lack of sleep, and not the sleep of a population of other subjects, you can probably simply identity those items that are correlated with your poor sleep patterns.  Once those variables have been identified through traditional analyses, they could be altered one by one until you've optimized your sleep.

Comment: Denislexic, Google causal inference. There are several moocs on it now.  Basically you need to set up experiments. Other than that linear regression is your friend, with such little data.